# How to fix org.neo4j.internal.unsafe.NativeMemoryAllocationRefusedError?

Tags: java, memory, neo4j, size

would be happy for any help regarding the following Problem.
I need to create a neo4j Graph out of words of documents. It always worked fine for 1000 Documents, but for 3000 Documents i get this memory error. I already uincreased the heap size with -Xmx4096m, but that didnt solve the problem. I would be thankfull for any answers to this problem.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.internal.unsafe.NativeMemoryAllocationRefusedError: Failed to allocate 524288 bytes. So far 36235008 bytes have already been successfully allocated. The system currently has 16930299904 bytes total physical memory, 57805078528 bytes committed virtual memory, and 570298368 bytes free physical memory. Relevant system properties: "java.vm.name" = "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM", "java.vm.vendor" = "OpenLogic", "os.arch" = "amd64".
    at org.neo4j.internal.unsafe.UnsafeUtil.allocateMemory(UnsafeUtil.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.io.mem.GrabAllocator$Grab.<init>(GrabAllocator.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.io.mem.GrabAllocator$Grabs.allocateAligned(GrabAllocator.java:244)
    at org.neo4j.io.mem.GrabAllocator.allocateAligned(GrabAllocator.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.PageList.initBuffer(PageList.java:299)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCursor.pageFault(MuninnPageCursor.java:419)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCursor.uncommonPin(MuninnPageCursor.java:369)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCursor.pin(MuninnPageCursor.java:337)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnReadPageCursor.next(MuninnReadPageCursor.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCursor.next(MuninnPageCursor.java:160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.readIntoRecord(CommonAbstractStore.java:885)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.getRecordByCursor(CommonAbstractStore.java:869)
    at org.neo4j.internal.recordstorage.RecordPropertyCursor.property(RecordPropertyCursor.java:439)
    at org.neo4j.internal.recordstorage.RecordPropertyCursor.next(RecordPropertyCursor.java:160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.DefaultPropertyCursor.next(DefaultPropertyCursor.java:163)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.DefaultPropertyCursor.seekProperty(DefaultPropertyCursor.java:235)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeEntity.getProperty(NodeEntity.java:439)
    at core.Cooccs.addSentenceToCooccsDB(Cooccs.java:661)
    at core.Cooccs.<init>(Cooccs.java:577)
    at core.TextProcessing.createDB(TextProcessing.java:386)
    at core.TextProcessing.main(TextProcessing.java:1085)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use batching to reduce the memory requirements of individual transaction(s).

You can do batching with a [CALL subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#_batching) or APOC [procedures for batch transactions](https://neo4j.com/docs/apoc/current/graph-updates/periodic-execution/#periodic-execution-proc-overview).